# XDocument Validate extension method does not show in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extension-methods

I'm trying to add a schema validation feature to a C# script I made;
it basically  loads data from Excel into a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and validates it before saving to file system.

I have already added the statement

```
using System.Xml.Schema;
```

but the [Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340331.aspx) method does does not show in intellisense (Visual Studio 2005).

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, VS 2005 is for .NET 2.0, and extension methods are only a language feature since .NET 3.0...

Thomas

Comment: you are right, there is some trick [here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Using-Extension-Methods-In-Fx-20-Projects.aspx) to let it work but I'm going to install Visual Studio 2010 to resolve the problem at the root.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referencing `System.Xml.Linq` in your project?

Comment: of course I am, the script works well; I have just to implement the validate part.

Comment: @systempuntoout like others of said Visual Studio 2.0, to be exact, .NET Framework 2.0 cannot reference System.Xml.Linq which is required to use the XDocument class.

Comment: @Ramhound I used XDocument class without any problem, why?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Visual Studio 2005 you should be using the following class instead.

.NET 2.0: [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

XMLDocument: [Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmldocument.validate%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) Method